# SQL 2000 - Enterprise Manager & Triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

We use SQL 2000 Enterprise Edition.

We have noticed that the triggers are not executed when we make data changes using the Enterprise Manager. That is, we execute a "Select" query, and we edit the results directly in the grid results table. The trigger is valid since it is executed as expected if we run an update query.

I am just wondering whether this is an expected behaviour. How does the Enterprise Manager manage to update the data without executing the triggers?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this scenario on a SQL 2000 database and it worked fine for me. Are you sure you're saving the changes as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275868(v=SQL.80).aspx)?

> Save your changes by moving to another
>   row in the grid.
>
> **Note**: The Query Designer or View Designer does not automatically save
>   your changes if you switch to another
>   pane. If you edit the current query
>   (for example, by making a change in
>   the Grid Pane), the Results pane is
>   dimmed. However, it is still active,
>   and you can still edit and save the
>   row on which you had been working.

Comment: Probably it was my mistake. I started over again and it works as expected. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, you should not ever make changes to the data in using Enterprise manager. You can create horrible problems this way. If the table is large it may go to absolutely silly lengths (such as creating new table and populating it rather than updating the record) to get the data in. Never make any data change except through a script.